# I can't get the date from date input value to another var angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I have  a date input that for some reason keeps becoming undefined or " d- n- u" when I try to use in my scope variable. 
Thought I have a watch for this input and the value is not undefined in there.
I can't seem to get this to work

html:

```
<input type="date" id="date-input2" ng-model="params.schedule" />
```

javaScript:

```
$scope.$watch('params.schedule', function (newValue, oldValue) {
//here I am indeed getting Mon Dec 31 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Western European //Standard Time)
        console.log(newValue);
        console.log($scope.params.schedule);

    }, true);
```

//but when I try to use it it becomes `undefined`... and then `d-n-u`...because of it

```
var scheduledDate = $scope.params.schedule;
$scope.params.schedule = scheduledDate[2] + "- " + scheduledDate[1] + "- " + scheduledDate[0];
$scope.ScheduledDate = scheduledDate.substring(0, 10);
```

why is the value getting lost midway?

Comment: what is the value of scheduledDate ?

Comment: @Sajeetharan "undefined- undefined- undefined"

Comment: try to provide plunkr for this. It will be more helpful to understand.

Comment: Instead of using a watcher, use the `ng-change` directive. It only fires on user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the value of  **`$scope.params.schedule`** within the $scope.$watch itself but not outside,

```
$scope.$watch('params.schedule', function (newValue, oldValue) {
//here I am indeed getting Mon Dec 31 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Western European //Standard Time)
var scheduledDate = $scope.params.schedule;
$scope.params.schedule = scheduledDate[2] + "- " + scheduledDate[1] + "- " + scheduledDate[0];
$scope.ScheduledDate = scheduledDate.substring(0, 10);
}, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the date is used as a string by JS:

```
var scheduledDate = $scope.params.schedule;
// scheduledDate is now equal to the date object "Mon Dec 31 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0000"
$scope.params.schedule = scheduledDate[2] + "- " + scheduledDate[1] + "- " + scheduledDate[0];
// Now $scope.params.schedule is parsed as a string by JS (you can't iterate on a date object) and equal to the 3rd char of the string, dash, 2nd char, dash, 1st char
// So $scope.params.schedule is equal to d- n- u
```

I would recommend using momentjs or another library to deal with dates, unless you don't use them much in your application.